# Cassandra Query Execution Time Calculation

Tags: cassandra, execution-time

Is there a way to calculate the query execution time in Cassandra 1.1 using cql or the cli? Is there any other way?  I am not able to find any solution. Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [tracing in cqlsh](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2). It provides time-stamps for each stage of the query, with millisecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze the query execution time / read performance in Cassandra you can find following stats helpful.

1) **nodetool cfstats:**
it provides the stats about number of parameter one of which is Read latency.

2) **Cassandra Cli:** when you query cassandra using cassandra-cli it shows "Elapsed time in msecs" (not sure if that is the exact time taken but it could be helpful in comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command for linux:

`cqlsh> TRACING ON`

You can read more from this link:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer as opposed to a link as webpages come and go but SO is forever. ;)